# How to wait for detected LVM volumes?

Tags: lvm, udev

I have the following problem: I have a machine running arch and which contains a encrypted LV in a LVM.
Inside the (encrypted) LV is another PV located. So I have in fact two VGs: One which contains the unencrypted data and one that contains only encrypted data.

I am now trying to get things running smoothly. I have scripts to scan for the PV in the encrypted volume and mount things. Unfortunately this does not work well due to timing problems.

As far as I can tell, when I invoke `pvscan`, `vgscan` or `lvscan` the disks are searched for a LVM signature and if such is found the new VG is activated. This works so far. Then `udev` is notified and creates different links under `/dev`.
Unfortunately this happens asynchronously. Thus my script continued running and did not find the links needed to check/mount the file systems.

So my questions:

- Is there a possibility to wait for `udev` until all links are generated and ready to be used?
- Is there a possibility to register a rule in `udev` that will call a script with all links as parameters/environ variables/...?
- Is there a possibility to register a rule that matches a link generated via `udev` instead the block device itself?
- Is there a way to wait until `vgscan` & Co. have terminated and `udev` has settled?

If you have another idea, I would like to hear it.

Comment: LVM inside LVM is very unusual, so I would not be surprised if it was not supported by default. Also when the first disk dies (with the LUKS header), you lose everything. Most people encrypt the PVs or specific LVs.

Comment: Hello, the encryption is not LUKS but plain crypt. Further you lose you VG in case your encrypted PV dies. It is all the same.

Comment: If you have multiple encrypted PV, you only lose the LV that was actually located on the lost PV and keep the others. If you make LVM stretch multiple PV first, encrypt that, and LVM it again, it's a bit different... anyway, good reason not to stick to standard solution? None of my business I guess, not sure if you'll get an answer. Good luck.

Comment: @frostschutz The reason is that I want to have the advantage of lvm to be able to expand a partition on-the-fly. Now not all my partitions must be encrypted. In fact only a subset can be encrypted or I get other problems with the booting (other issue I solved already). To be free how much memory is encrypted I created the unencrypted LVs and one big LV for the encrypted PV. If I encrypted the PVs directly, I had to decide on the sizes of both parts (encrypted and not encrypted) a priori.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is a bit unusual (LVM inside LVM).

In general you should rely on udev as much as possible and not rely on your own scripts too much, i.e. trigger one action and let udev/systemd handle the rest in an event-triggered manner (instead of sequentially running commands in some script)!  Also take care to scan only your device and not "everything".

You may also read `69-lvm-metad.rules` and use `udevadm monitor` to see  what is happening.

Still I will answer some of your questions as well.

## Running a script for a device node

To run a script you can use `RUN` in an udev-rule. Note that `RUN` is asynchronous and is run *after* the rule has been processed (in contrast to `PROGRAM`)

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdb", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/some_script"
```

udev will call your script with environment variables in accordance to the variables in your udev-event, i.e. `KERNEL`, `ACTION` etc.

You can also match for a symlink, of course, but in order to get your job done I would match against the actual device and probably specify it further instead of relying on the name of a symlink. You can use `udevadm monitor --property` to see the different events including their properties (unique ids etc.) Also note that the links get appended, so it might be difficult to match (have not checked this myself).

```
   SYMLINK
       Match the name of a symlink targeting the node. It can be used once a SYMLINK key has been set in one of the preceding
       rules. There may be multiple symlinks; only one needs to match.
```

## Waiting for udev events to be handled

```
udevadm settle
```

will block until all udev events are handled. It also has parameters for a timeout or to wait for a specific file to appear, but for your use case running it without parameters should be enough.

Quoting the [udevadm-manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm):

```
udevadm settle [options]
    Watches the udev event queue, and exits if all current events are handled.
```